# Convert a JSON string to multiple CSV's based on its structure and name it to a certain value

Tags: python, json, csv

I currently have A JSON file saved containing some data I want to convert to CSV. Here is the data sample below, **please note, I have censored the actual value in there for security and privacy reasons.**

```
{
    "ID value1": {
        "Id": "ID value1",
        "TechnischContactpersoon": {
            "Naam": "Value",
            "Telefoon": "Value",
            "Email": "Value"
        },
        "Disclaimer": [
            "Value"
        ],
        "Voorzorgsmaatregelen": [
            {
                "Attributes": {},
                "FileId": "value",
                "FileName": "value",
                "FilePackageLocation": "value"
            },
            {
                "Attributes": {},
                "FileId": "value",
                "FileName": "value",
                "FilePackageLocation": "value"
            },
        ]
    },
    "ID value2": {
        "Id": "id value2",
        "TechnischContactpersoon": {
            "Naam": "Value",
            "Telefoon": "Value",
            "Email": "Value"
        },
        "Disclaimer": [
            "Placeholder"
        ],
        "Voorzorgsmaatregelen": [
            {
                "Attributes": {},
                "FileId": "value",
                "FileName": "value",
                "FilePackageLocation": "value"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Though I know how to do this (because I already have a function to handle a JSON to CSV convertion) with a simple JSON string without issues. I do not know to this with this kind of JSON file that this kind of a structure layer. Aka a second layer beneath the first. Also you may have noticed that there is an ID value above

Because as may have noticed from structure is actually another layer inside the JSON file. So in total I need to have two kinds of CSV files:

1. The main CSV file just containing the ID, Disclaimer. This CSV file
   is called utility networks and contains all possible ID value's and
   the value
2. A file containing the "Voorzorgsmaatregelen" value's. Because there are multiple values in this section, one CSV file per unique
   ID file is needed and needs to be named after the Unique value id.

Deleted this part because it was irrelevant.

```
Data_folder = "Data"
Unazones_file_name = "UnaZones"
Utilitynetworks_file_name = "utilityNetworks"
folder_path_JSON_BS_JSON = folder_path_creation(Data_folder)

pkml_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path_JSON_BS_JSON,"pmkl.json")

print(pkml_file_path)

json_object = json_open(pkml_file_path)

json_content_unazones = json_object.get("mapRequest").get("UnaZones")
json_content_utility_Networks = json_object.get("utilityNetworks")

Unazones_json_location = json_to_save(json_content_unazones,folder_path_JSON_BS_JSON,Unazones_file_name)
csv_file_location_unazones = os.path.join(folder_path_CSV_file_path(Data_folder),(Unazones_file_name+".csv"))

csv_file_location_Utilitynetwork = os.path.join(folder_path_CSV_file_path(Data_folder),(Unazones_file_name+".csv"))
    
json_content_utility_Networks = json_object.get("utilityNetworks")

Utility_networks_json_location = json_to_save(json_content_utility_Networks,folder_path_JSON_BS_JSON,Utilitynetworks_file_name)

def json_to_csv_convertion(json_file_path: str, csv_file_location: str):
    loaded_json_data = json_open(json_file_path)
    # now we will open a file for writing
    data_file = open(csv_file_location, 'w', newline='')
    # # create the csv writer object
    csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file,delimiter = ";")
 
# Counter variable used for writing
# headers to the CSV file
    count = 0
    for row in loaded_json_data:
        if count == 0:
        # Writing headers of CSV file
            header = row.keys()
            csv_writer.writerow(header)
            count += 1
        # Writing data of CSV file
        csv_writer.writerow(row.values())
    data_file.close()
```

def folder_path_creation(path: str):
if not os.path.exists(path):
os.makedirs(path)
return path

```
def json_open(complete_folder_path):
    with open(complete_folder_path) as f:
        json_to_load = json.load(f)  # Modified "objectids" to "object_ids" for readability -sg
    return json_to_load

def json_to_save(input_json, folder_path: str, file_name: str):
    json_save_location = save_file(input_json, folder_path, file_name, "json")
    return json_save_location
```

So how do I this starting from this?

```
for obj in json_content_utility_Networks:
```

Go from there?

Keep in mind that is  JSON value has already **one layer above every object** for every object I need to start one layer below it.

**So how do I this?**

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] (MRE) — there's way too much irrelevant information in your question IMO. Try to reduce it to the essence of what you want to know or do.

Comment: Are "ID value1" and "id value1" actually supposed to be the same string?  If so, it looks like your JSON has been generated by taking a list of dictionaries and turning it into a dictionary of dictionaries using one of its values, and what you used to working with is just a list of dictionaries.  Is that correct?

Comment: They are supposed to be same string. I have taken this part of the JSON from a feature collection JSON aka a GeoJSON this is data that is not "part" of the features.